# How Can I Deserialize JSON Data Using C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have seen some other questions like this, but those are quite complex JSON data's that have objects within objects. Although the JSON I'm working with is never static, I doubt it's as complex as those. Also, it's my first time using JSON with C# so I'm a little clueless.

What I'm trying to achieve is to separate the data that is received from an API that I prompt using WebRequest in C#.

```
{
    "johhny.debt": {
         "id":35187540,
         "name":"johnny.debt",
         "profileIconId":786,
         "Level":30,
         "revisionDate":1428019045000
     }
 }
```

The returned JSON data is in a fashion like thereof.

I want to be able to access all of the properties of the above string in the following manner:

ID :
Name:
~~
~~ 
~~
... and so forth.

I'm assuming some type of class has to be made for this?

All help is appreciated, thank you all in advance.

Comment: Just define a class which reflects your structure and `Deserialize` into this class.

Comment: @DrKoch Believe it or not that is what I need help with.

Comment: tried google? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Json.Net from Nuget

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Declare class for inner object (`{"id":..., "name": ... }`):

```
public class InnerObject
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string  Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("profileIconId")]
    public int ProfileIconId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("level")]
    public int Level { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("revisionDate")]
    public string RevisionDate { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see you can specify rename mapping from json fields to .Net object properties using `JsonPropertyAttribute`.

Read your json to `Dictionary<string,InnerObject>` and get value of "johhny.debt" key:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, InnerObject>>(jsonText);
var johhny = dict["johhny.debt"];
```

---

Or if your need always to parse *exact* json property 'johhny.debt', you could create root object class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("johhny.debt")]
    public InnerObject JohhnyDept { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize it:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
var johhny = root.JohhnyDebt;
```

Comment: Beautifully explained. I'm assuming the JSON is now deserliazed and put in an object, how would I exactly access the properties in the best way?

Comment: dict["info"].property perhaps?

Comment: As simple object property. Example: `Console.Write("Name is " + johhny.Name);`

Comment: If you need to read extra data from root object have a look at         `JsonExtensionDataAttribute`

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Other { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Just Create a class like this

```
  public class RootObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string revisionDate { get; set; }
}
```

then install json.Net and this code to your main method

```
var jsonObject=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
```

That's all

**Update**

```
 var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
    var RootObject = new RootObject()
    {
        Id = (int)obj["johhny.debt"]["id"],
        Level = (int)obj["johhny.debt"]["Level"],
        name = (string)obj["johhny.debt"]["name"],
        profileIconId = (int)obj["johhny.debt"]["profileIconId"],
        revisionDate = (string)obj["johhny.debt"]["revisionDate"]
    };
```

Comment: I think you need a second level class. First level is "johny.dept". This property contains the second level class.

Comment: The format of your json has changed from you previous post wait a second i will update the asnwer